# Should I disable or enable Transparent Huge Pages for performance?

Tags: linux, magento, redis, centos, varnish

I have varnish 6.2 and Redis 5 with magento 2.3 on same box running centos 7. Should I disable or enable Transparent Huge Pages for performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable it, please. It's known to impact Varnish performance.
(not sure about Redis and Magento)

Answer (score 1):

Same recommendation for Redis: '*...when a Linux kernel has transparent huge pages enabled, Redis incurs to a big latency penalty after the fork call is used in order to persist on disk*' [1][2].

[1] https://redis.io/topics/latency

[2] [When to turn off Transparent Huge Pages for redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591511/when-to-turn-off-transparent-huge-pages-for-redis)